# How do I create a build with git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm a front-end developer. I just started with a new company that uses a development firm for all of their back-end stuff. They use GitHub and git command line, while my old position used BitBucket so there's a bit of a learning curve. At my old company, BitBucket had testing environments for each branch, so I never had to worry about testing my changes locally. After spending all day Googling, I've learned that I need to create a build for my local clone.

My question is: how exactly do I do that? Since my changes are front-end, I want to visually look at them before submitting a pull request, so I need to look at everything in-browser. Here's what the development firm told me, with the problematic instructions bolded:

> Develop on your local install and **test there**. If all is good, it
>   gets pushed to the dev site for further testing. If everything checks
>   out, then it gets pushed to production.

I'd ask them for clarification, but it's hard to get a hold of them for the most part. Can anyone help me?

Edit / It's a Magento site if that helps anything.

Comment: Why not read the git documentation, or the github.com guide - literally the /FIRST BUTTON/ front and center on he home page??     Please make an effort to asnwer your question before posting it here!

Comment: Uh, I did. There's no need to be rude. I've spend ~4 hours researching this and can't find a clear answer. For instance, on GitHub's guide, the answer I need would be somewhere between step 3 and 4, but it's not clearly defined. I'm asking about testing in-browser, not the commit/push/etc. processes.

Comment: Casey - Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You haven't even begun to provide enough information for anyone to help you here.  This forum is for specific programming questions.   If you don't know how to build / test software, it is not the place to ask for an intro on software.   If you don't know how to build / test software build with specific technologies or tools, then please tell us what technologies, languages or tools you are using, what you've tried before, and the exact problem you are having.  I'm trying to help here, this is an extremely low-quality question.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that Git is merely a version control system (or a file system with pretensions of being a version control system :-) ), and not a build and/or test system.  Those are all outside the scope of Git itself, although they may be integrated together in some way.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I may have taken that for granted, given that everything in my previous role was integrated with BitBucket. I've asked the dev firm if they use anything similar, and they keep stressing to me that all I need is git command line, which may be why I'm so baffled by this. Thank you for the clarification torek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a working environment on your local machine (can be on your machine directly, or inside a docker container or inside a vagrant created VM) **with all tools that you are using for your project** installed (gulp, grunt, karma, npm, bower?) and after updating the code, you need to run tests locally (`$ mocha --recursive`, `$ npm test` - or whatever you use to run your tests), and view your changes in a browser (I assume you have a web server with PHP since it's a Magento project). After tests pass on your local machine, you push the changes to a proper branch - and it seems like there it works same as before in your BitBucket set-up.

Ask the other company if they have any images or scripts for building your local environment (they might use, vagrant, Chef, Docker, etc) which would make things easier for you.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for, and it's extremely helpful.